# Javascript - If Statement Returning Null Despite Condition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why my if statement is sending true output's despite accounting for null situations in my if statement. Can someone explain what is wrong with my conditions and the reason why null triggers for true?

```
if(startDate || startDate != null){
            filterQuery.push('dateStart=' + startDate);
}
```

outputs `dateStart=null` in instances where there is a null value.

Comment: What does `typeof startDate;` returns?

Comment: If `startDate` is really `null`, that condition will definitely be false. (It will also be false if `startDate` is `undefined`.)

Comment: It returns string

Comment: There's no need for the first part of that condition, though.

Comment: Don't tell me it is the string `"null"`, that would be really funny. Whoever thinks assigning the string `"null"` to a variable is a good idea, is asking for getting confused.

Comment: `null` should be `"object"` type, you `startDate` is actually `"null"`, not `null`, hence condition 1 is true.

Comment: `startDate` appears to be `"null"`. Can you show us how you defined this value? Please, [edit] your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331592/javascript-if-statement-returning-null-despite-condition/42331662#comment71815723_42331592) that `typeof startDate` gives you `"string"`. That's your problem: `"null"` is a truthy value (so it passes the first test) that is `!= null` (so it passes the second test). So your condition is true and the output concatenate the *string* `"null"` to your error message.

Comment: Great call. I should have defaulted to using `typeof` before jumping to the assumption that it was an actual `null` value